# php echo something between 2 functions after an AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking for a way to get an echo (or anything else) between 2 functions, the first being called via Ajax.

Here is what I am doing :

I upload via Ajax a video to the server where it is temporary stored.
then pass the video to a private function that send it to youtube via the API and after, unset the video on the server.

My question : between the 2 functions, is there a way to get from the PHP script something that can be handled by the client to inform him of the progress ?

I tried :

- to send JSon
- to update a session checked by JS while the Ajax call
- flush() and ob_flush()

but always, data is returned at this end of the 2nd function (when I don't need anything anymore), as if, while the call and all that is after, PHP was unable to say something

I 'd like :

```
function upload()
{
    //uploading
    if(ok) 
    {
        //echoing something there (the main goal)
        goYoutube();
    }
}

private function goYoutube() {
//etc...
}
```

and what I have is :

```
 function upload()
 {
    //uploading
    if(ok) 
    {
        goYoutube();
    }
}

private function goYoutube() 
{
    //etc...
    //echoing something there (the bad bad bad useless thing)
}
```

It is with CodeIgniter and I don't have the hand on the server.

I don't need code, just an idea (which will be greatly appreciated)

Of course, something like "don't lose your time guy, it can't be done" is ok !

Thanks.

Comment: You can send separate request from JS to request status of current operation. Then you will need way to get this status. Or also you can think about using SSE or WebSocket and send progress directly to client.

Comment: @AntonM. Yea i have found the mid flushing during long script frustrating... - It's complicated from the point of PHP itself and then you have to deal with Webserver too... Easiest would probably be periodical ajax calling some script with generated ID and during long script store progress information into sessionvar, that will be returned by the script called by ajax.

Comment: Thx, I already have a xhr progress for the upload itself actually (not that precise, but well... it's ok), what I am trying to get is the point where the PHP runs the "goyoutube" function (or ends the upload one) ; I get it, but when all is finished.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server side language and I don't think it'll output something until the script finished executing. If I were you I would try to split those functions in two separate AJAX request.

The first request gives the user the answer that everything is ok (or something like "please wait") and the second request makes the call to the YouTube API.

Comment: And progress something like "0-100%" could be stored in session var... it's not a confidential data anyway.

Comment: Yes. Or you can estimate that "it's not taking longer than x seconds" and make a nice progress bar with Javascript so  you'll not loose the user because he doesn't know what's happening.

Comment: @Alex Spataru, thx, it is a way, but I would like my youtube function name not to be on the client side in anyway, and at the moment, all works fine with the upload and  this private function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by establishing a websocket connection and sending events from the server to the client. I usually do this in nodejs using socket.io. I see there is a similar option for PHP: [elephant.io](http://elephant.io/)

So the order of things would be:

- Establish websockets connection with server (before sending video)
- In the clientside, listen for the event you will receive and do whatever update there.
- Do the video upload.
- In the serverside, send a websockets event where you would place you "echo"

Take a look at it, I really think it will do.

Comment: Thx for your solution, although I got a default way by comparing the uploaded part and the total size to get a point, I keep it by me for a future use.  Thanks to all !